# Find characteristic polynomial of $\,A^2$ if the characteristic polynomial of $\,A$ is $\,t^4 -t$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> $A \in M_{4\times4}(\mathbb{R})$. The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $P_A(t)=t^4-t$. I have to find the characteristic polynomial of $A^2$ and $A^4$.

So I know that due to the Cayley–Hamilton theorem that $P_A(A) = A^4-A=0$ , therefore $A^4 = A$, Therefore  $P_{A^4}(t)=P_A(t)=t^4-t$.

But what do I do with  $A^2$?

I also know that the eigenvalues of A are $0,1$... how does this help?

Thank you all.

Comment: How do you justify your second "therefore"?

Comment: Hint 1: the characteristic polynomials of $A, A^2, A^4$ are the same if you see these real matrices as complex matrices. Hint 2: $t^4-t$ splits with distinct roots in $\mathbb{C}$, hence $A$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Since $A^4=A$ implies $(A^2)^4=A^2$ i.e., $t^4-t$ is a monic polynomial of degree 4 annihilating $A^2$; can we not conclude that the char poly is $t^4-t$ itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***For $\mathbb{C}$:***

The eigenvalues of $A$ are $0,1,e,e^2$ where $e$ is a primitive root out $1$: $e^3=1$. Hence the eigenvalues of $A^2$ and also of $A^4$ are $0,1,e^2, e^4=e$ i.e. the same. So the characteristic polynomials of $A^2$ and $A^4$ also are $t^4-t$.

***For $\mathbb{R}$:***

Сharacteristic polynomials of $A^2$ and $A^4$ do not change, i.e. $t^4-t$.

**Addendum:** Theorem from the Gantmacher's book: If $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues of $A$ and $g(x)$ a polynomial, then $g(\lambda_1),\ldots,g(\lambda_n)$ are the eigenvalues of $g(A)$ (with the same multiplicities).

Comment: Thank you but I didn't understand. what are these $e,e^2$ and where did they came from? and why the eigenvalues of $A^2 and A^4$ are $0,1,e^2,e^4$? notice that we are talking about $\mathbb{R}$, not $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: It follows from a property: if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ then $\lambda^n$ is an eigenvalue of $A^n$ for every $n\ge 0$.

Comment: What about my first question? What are $e,e^2$? the eigenvalues of A are all the roots of $t^4-t=0$. $t^4-t=0$ <==> $t=0$ or $t=1$, when we deal with $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Sorry, I considered $\mathbb{C}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$. I will correct yhe answer.

Comment: Why does the fact that $A,A^2$ have the same eigenvalues, say that they have the same characteristic polynomial? Couldn't it be that one is $t^4-t$ and the other is $t^4-t^3$? Both these have ${0,1}$ as roots and $deg=4$, however they are not the same...

Comment: The roots must have the same multiplicity.

Comment: Why? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: See, for example, Gantmacher F.R.The theory of matrices, vol.1, chapt.IV, sec.4, theorem 3, p.84.

Comment: @Dor Shalom: I added the answer.